# Is iteration process through equal sign possible?

Tags: calculus

Is iteration process through equal sign possible?

for an example: [repeatedly pressing on the equal button of calculator](http://easteinstein.wordpress.com/2013/03/02/math-on-the-equal-button-of-calculator/)

> Repeatedly pressing on the equal button of calculator until full converging the Answer.

this is (Ahmad Reza Estakhr's) symbol of iteration of equal sign $\Re_{i=1}^{\infty}=$ which means repeatedly pressing on equal sign.

Answer (score 2):

That just depends on **what the equal sign on your calculator is programmed to do**.

Usually the equal sign is meant to compute as much as it can (in your terms, carry out as many "iterations" in one step as possible) - if you type in 5+(3*2)+8+9, it will return 28, instead of returning 5+6+8+9.

It's possible, yes, for certain cases (e.g. if your calculator is a polynomial solver), especially if your equal sign is programmed to carry out simplification; however, by and large, it will just land you returning the same value over and over again. In other words, the general answer to your question is no.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: yes, probably, subject to a few caveats. Here are two I can think of:

- it must be running an algorithm that will actually converge (it's sometimes rather hard to prove that an algorithm converges with a given input, e.g. Newton-Raphson with a given polynomial and 'starting value'),
- it must be performing an algorithm that isn't very sensitive to rounding errors (because calculators will make them!).

But there are probably more.

Answer (score 1):

yes, it is possible, for example M-set $ z_{n+1}=z_{n}^2+c $ in term of Estakhr's Iteration symbol is this like:

$$Ans^2+c\Re_{i=1}^{\infty}=Ans$$

Interestingly M-set under Estakhr's iteration equation of the complex quadratic polynomial $Ans^2+c\Re_{i=1}^{\infty}=Ans$ remains bounded, that which means M-set remains bounded (because of imaginary number) but it does not converge to a limit.